# apt-get install halted because of too many errors

Tags: linux, python-3.x, apt, linux-mint

So it all started when I somehow broke python3, running it (even just the repl) resulted in the following error: `[1]   <some four-digit number> Illegal hardware instruction python3`

I decided to try to re-install it. This turned out to be a bad idea. The uninstallation process halted because of too many errors, leaving a similar error message. If I try to install something, `apt-get` stops because of too many errors, even if I try to install something that is already installed

Here is a sample error message: https://pastebin.com/dSp9ecuw

Here is a part of the error message that is fairly representative (most of it is just this but with different package names):

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 132
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-chardet:
 python3-chardet depends on python3-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python3-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
```

This is also what the end looks like:

```
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-apt
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 dh-python
 python3-commandnotfound
 python3-dbus
 python3-gi
 ufw
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-chardet
 ...
 (and so on for a bunch of packages)
 ...
 python3-oneconf
 sessioninstaller
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```